# How can I restart Finder when it keeps "stopping" an stopped copy process?

Tags: macos, finder

Every now and then, mostly with USB sticks, Finder decides to copy forever, either at the end of the copy process (i.e. the files are already copied), or at the very beginning.

Stopping the process in the little window will make Finder announce that it is "stopping" and it will do that for a few hours.

[image: Been "Stopping..." for hours, probably will keep at it forever!]

I tried just killing and restarting Finder but the old Finder survives as a zombie and the new Finder never finished starting.

Is there another way of recovering from this problem other than restarting the computer?

Since I upgraded to Lion I found that restarts have become more common.

**Update:** In Mountain Lion it would appear you can't even restart to fix it!

[image: THe Finder can't quit because some operations are still in progress. (And will be forever!)]

Comment: Did you use `killall Finder` (which sends a TERM signal) or did you use `killall -KILL Finder`?

Comment: I used the GUI thingy. I don't know what it does.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had it complete after hanging there for at least 10 minutes. So if it hasn't been hours yet, it's possible that it will recover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next time this happens, look at the Finder process using `ps`: First run this in a terminal:

```
launchctl list | grep Finder
```

The output should be just one line, listing `com.apple.Finder` with a number at the beginning of the line. That number is the process ID (pid) of Finder. Now run

```
ps up xxx
```

replacing xxx by the pid found in the first step. Look under the STAT heading. If you see the letter U then the Finder is stuck in an uninterruptible system call, and cannot be killed. You will most likely need to restart your system to recover.

Processes stuck in an uninterruptible system call is often a symptom of a hardware problem. It would bear further investigations to find the cause.

Comment: The hardware problem is most likely the USB stick Finder is copying to. So I will have to use something else to copy files if Finder is too fragile.

Comment: What if the letter is `?E+` or `?E`, and launchctl list | grep Finder yields `7709 - 0x7fe8cd22f820.anonymous.Finder
7698 - 0x7fe8cb40b0f0.anonymous.Finder
470 - com.apple.Finder`?

Comment: @daviewales The normal finder process would be the one without “anonymous” in its label. I have no idea what caused the other two to exist, but could speculate that Finder fires off new processes to handle copying or other tasks, and those are what you see. The letter E in the status indicate that the process is trying to exit, according to the manual page for ps. Not too sure what that means either, but maybe there are pending writes that need to be finished before the process can exit.

Comment: I had a Finder mega crash, so I think the other two things appeared as a result of me trying to launch Finder when the previous instance hadn't properly exited yet. (Incidentally, I was unable to stop any of the Finder instances without force restarting, which was annoying.)

Comment: In my instance when it actually did recover, it showed `S`, which `man ps` says `Marks a process that is sleeping for less than about 20 seconds.`

Answer (score 3):

```
killall Finder
```

If you don't have `killall`

```
brew install killall
```

if you don't have `brew`

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

if you don't have `ruby`

You have it, it comes with OSX

Answer (score 0):

If it hasn't frozen completely, you can also how down ALT/Option on your keyboard and either right-click the Finder icon in the dock or click the Finder menu in the menubar. Either way, you'll then see an option to force restart Finder.

Comment: I did that and the above-described symptoms appeared.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Command</kbd>  <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd>, Relaunch Finder, 
Done

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: Note that in the question it specifically says that that method doesn't work.