# What does Force Quit do in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications

How does the GUI interface for *force quitting* applications (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>) work?

e.g.
Does it work like `killall Finder` which would send a `TERM` signal by default?

Comment: I would expect it to send a KILL signal, possibly after trying less drastic signals first. Otherwise, a hung process might not be terminated after all. But I don't know what it actually does.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I would expect that aswell, but [this question & comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/53735/13414) suggest something less radical.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems clear that Force Quit treats Finder differently. Just notice how the text of the “Force Quit” button changes when you choose the Finder. Or perhaps the problem is that Finder is stuck in an uninterruptible system call, in which case even a KILL signal will not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just probed this with `dtrace`. The PID of the program in question is sent a `SIGTERM` (i.e., signal 15) from `loginwindow`.

I also tried this with a stopped process (sent `SIGSTOP`), so that the process showed as "Not Responding" in the Force Quit dialog and got the same result, `loginwindow` sends a `SIGTERM`.

If you want to try yourself, run the following in Terminal:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/dtrace -n 'proc:::signal-send /pid/ { printf("%s -%d %d",execname,args[2],args[1]->pr_pid); }'
```

You'll then see the name of the process sending the signal, the signal number and the PID the signal is sent to.

Comment: If you try force quitting a background processes (or an app that isn't shown in the Dock) from Activity Monitor, most of them seem to be sent a SIGKILL (-9) instead.

Comment: @LauriRanta: Nice. I didn't try that.

Comment: @bahamat, thanks for the answer, but I wonder if you can say which version of OS X you tried this on.

Comment: Judging by when I originally posted this, I'd say it was 10.7.x. It still works on Yosemite. You need to be root or use `sudo` though.