# macOS Monterey (12.7) - process showing status in paranthesis does not have a parent process, thus cannot be killed that way

Tags: macos

Attempting to kill a process showing in paranthesis as status, using various options of kill (-1, -9, etc.) obviously does not work:

```
$ ps ax | grep my_process

86103   ??  ?E     0:00.00 (my_process)
```

and the [instructions here](https://super-unix.com/askdifferent/macos-cannot-kill-process-shown-in-parenthesis/) are of no use, either:

```
$ ps lw | egrep '[ ](86103|PID)'

  UID   PID  PPID CPU PRI NI      VSZ    RSS WCHAN  STAT   TT       TIME COMMAND

<... nothing here ...>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the process called?

Comment: The task is a zombie - see this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87020/237 I think I have  provided a fuller answer here but I can't find that

Comment: The name of the process is irrelevant, but as @mmmmmm stated, this could be in a zombie state.  However it could also mean it’s in an orphan state.  Bottom line is both can cause resources to be unavailable

Comment: I just need to run a fresh instance, but when trying to do so ($ open -n /Applications/my_process.app), the system finds the zombie/ghost/hung process, and refuses to reopen, so I am not sure how to use the info provided... ?!?

Comment: @PapiAntoniadis I think we need to know what the process is called and which app created it as there are other possible issue. If the app is a special one written for your company etc and the name can't be divulged then you need to ask the apps authors.

Comment: @PapiAntoniadis: The output from `ps ax | grep my_process` shows a process with no controlling terminal. The command `ps lw | egrep '[ ](86103|PID)'` shows no output because the process with id `86103` must have a controlling terminal. You should have entered `ps lwax | egrep '[ ](86103|PID)'`.