# Can't force quit frozen iTunes in OS X Yosemite

Tags: itunes, macos, applications

I have OS X Yosemite. Was adding a podcast to an older nano, and iTunes crashed. It's still running, but when I try it won't force quit. I tried to restart or shut down, but the system wants me to force quit Itunes, but it won't. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Run `killall -9 iTunes` in Terminal.

Comment: prompted me to Google 'why -9?'. Answers appear to make perfect sense, kills with no chance of interruption, no waiting for caches, updates etc... but my question, which wouldn't fit AD in its own right, what does Cmd/Opt/Esc + force-quit send?

Comment: @Tetsujin That would definitely be worth it's own question, but the abridged answer is that force quit sends SIGTERM (`-15`) whereas `-9` sends SIGKILL.

Comment: ahh, that would have been my guess, from my random googling. Glad to have it confirmed. One day I'll get my 'nix' up to speed… 25 years on Macs & I've only just since joining SE started to even glance at the underpinnings. I'll spin it out to a question, for future googlers.

Comment: would be a dupe of this - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53744/what-does-force-quit-do-in-os-x - but the correct answer there could use some love for not-quite-so techies, as it makes assumptions about existing knowledge level.